# Copy file to arbitrary directory in Wix?

Tags: installation, wix

This is a real newbie question, but I've read all the Wix introductions and the Wix cookbook and I'm clearly missing some vital context that's assumed by all of them.

I want to install a single file (a Microsoft Word template) to the user's Word STARTUP template directory (C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\STARTUP). I've not found a Wix example like that. Here's my attempt:

```
 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
     <Directory Id="AppDataFolder"> 
        <Directory Id="A1" Name="Microsoft">
            <Directory Id="A2" Name="Templates">
                <Directory Id="StartupTemplates" Name="STARTUP">
 </Directory></Directory></Directory></Directory></Directory>
  
  <DirectoryRef Id="StartupTemplates">
    <Component Id="ApplicationFiles" Guid="0E4812A6-AEC3-4B36-8654-E4FAA6XXXXXX">
        <File Id="TheTemplate" Source="ImageAndTableSupport.dotm"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="DeleteTheTemplate" Directory="StartupTemplates" On="uninstall"/>
    </Component>
 </DirectoryRef>

  <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
     <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationFiles"/>
  </Feature>
```

I get a slew of errors:

```
error LGHT0204 : ICE38: Component ApplicationFiles installs to user profile. It must use a registry key under HKCU as its KeyPath, not a file.
error LGHT0204 : ICE64: The directory A2 is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
error LGHT0204 : ICE64: The directory A1 is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
```

Also, it doesn't work. The installation prompts for admin privileges and something appears to be copied somewhere, but I can't find it. :)

How should I code this operation on Wix?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I got it in the end, after several hours more head bashing. Turns out Wix is all about setting configuration variables. So the line:

```
 <Directory Id='FRED'>
```

actually means 'Install inside the folder corresponding to configuration variable FRED'

Also Microsoft Installer doesn't seem to mind if it cannot do an action. It just fails silently. So if your path is wrong (as mine was), tough.

Here's working code (omitting standard media, product and package runes):

```
    <SetDirectory Id="STARTUP_TEMPLATES" Value="[AppDataFolder]\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP" />
    
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir"> <!-- Required by Wix -->
        <Directory Id="STARTUP_TEMPLATES">
            <Component Id="ApplicationFiles" Guid="0E4812A6-AEC3-4B36-8654-E4FAAXXXXXX" KeyPath="yes" >
                <File Id="TheTemplate" Source="ImageAndTableSupport.dotm" Vital="yes" />
            </Component>
        </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationFiles"/>
    </Feature>
```

The full implementation, including upgrade support (not trivial) is [here](https://github.com/charlesweir/WordImagesAndTables/blob/master/ImageAndTableSupport.wxs). Windows even checks if Word is using the file during uninstallation! Please be sure you change the UUIDs if you reuse it!

Comment: Best to redact your GUID so no one has a chance to clone it.

Comment: Thanks, but I did that, @ChristopherPainter - that's what the XXX's are.  But it's more difficult with the real implementation on GitHub. That's why my comment.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read all the characters.